# Animating highlight rectangle in XAML GridView

Tags: c#, xaml

Suppose I have a simple GridView like this ...

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="gridView1"     CanReorderItems="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    </GridView>    
</Grid>
```

The currently selected item has a highlight rectangle around it. When I press an arrow key the highlight rectangle will move to the next appropriate item in the grid. By default this happens instantly. I would rather have an animation of the highlight rectangle to the next item. Is there some way I can animate the transition of the highlight rectangle when it moves from one item to the next? I just want to see the highlight rectangle move to its new position over a period of milliseconds.

Thanks

Brian

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm currently customizing the GridViewItemPresenter to hide the default behavior. then I am going to try and float my own rectangle over the grid items and animate that when the selected item changes. I can't think of a better approach right now. I'm new to XAML.